# Javascript week range forward button and backward button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need some help here with my code. I have a forward button and backward button to supposedly dynamically display one week to the next and vice versa. I have the current week displayed on load. Problem is I can't seem to figure out how to make the forward and backward button continuously move from one week range to another. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="calendar.css">
    <title>Calendar</title>
</head>
<body onload="dateRange()">
    <script>

        function dateRange(){
            var start_date = "<?php echo $start_date = date("F d    Y",strtotime('monday this week')); ?>";
            var end_date = "<?php echo $end_date = date("F d Y",strtotime("sunday this week"));; ?>";
            document.getElementById('date_range').innerHTML = start_date + " - " + end_date;
    }
        function forward(){
            var start_date = "<?php echo $start_date = date('F d Y', strtotime('+1 weeks', strtotime($start_date))); ?>";
            var end_date = "<?php echo date('F d Y', strtotime('+1 weeks', strtotime($end_date))); ?>";
            document.getElementById('date_range').innerHTML = start_date + " - " + end_date;
         }
         function backward(){
            var start_date = "<?php echo date('F d Y', strtotime('-1 weeks', strtotime($start_date))); ?>";
            var end_date = "<?php echo date('F d Y', strtotime('-1 weeks', strtotime($end_date))); ?>";
            document.getElementById('date_range').innerHTML = start_date + " - " + end_date;
        }
    </script>
    <h1 id="date_range"></h1>
    <div>
        <input type="button" onClick="forward()" name="forward" value=">">
        <input type="button" onClick="backward()" name="backward" value="<">
    </div>
```

Could really use the help please and its very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing: It's not good practice to use PHP to populate your javascript. PHP is a server-side language, javascript (in this case) runs in the client's browser. This is going to make your code very difficult to maintain and debug, because you'll need to dig into the script to see how PHP output it.

You can do this all with javascript:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <h1 id="date_range"></h1>
  <div>
    <input type="button" onClick="backward()" name="backward" value="<">
    <input type="button" onClick="forward()" name="forward" value=">">
  </div>  
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
var range = document.getElementById('date_range');
var offset = 0;
var today = new Date();
var dayOfWeekOffset = today.getDay();


function getWeek(offset) {
  offset = offset || 0; // if the function did not supply a new offset, the offset is 0
  var firstDay = new Date();
  firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() - dayOfWeekOffset + (offset * 7));
    // .setDate() sets the date (1-31) of the current month.
    // The beginning of the week is:
    //    today's date (firstDay.getDate())
    //    minus the day of week offset to get us back to sunday (dayOfWeekOffset)
    //    plus the number of days we need to offset for future / past weeks (offset * 7) 

  var lastDay = new Date(firstDay);
  lastDay.setDate(lastDay.getDate() + 6);
    // the last day is the first day plus 6

  console.log(makeDateString(firstDay), makeDateString(lastDay));
  range.innerHTML = 'week of ' + makeDateString(firstDay) + ' - ' + makeDateString(lastDay);
}


function makeDateString(date) {
  var dd = date.getDate();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var dateString = mm + '/'+ dd + '/'+ y;
  return dateString;

}

function backward() {
  offset = offset - 1;
  getWeek(offset);
}

function forward() {
  offset = offset + 1;
  getWeek(offset);
}

window.onload = function() {
  getWeek();
}
```

Working JSBin here: http://jsbin.com/lawuyawoka/

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. I'm trying your code right now but I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" and it points to the line with range.innerHTML. Any ideas please?

Comment: When you see an error like this, it means that `range` is null, and not a DOM node like we are expecting. (If you console.log(range), it will return 'null'). It looks like the `var range` that we are setting is not finding the correct element in your DOM - looking at my code compared to yours, it's because I've used a hyphen and you used an underscore. Try changing the `id` of the range div to `date-range`, or have the script look for `date_range` instead of `date-range`

Comment: @KenichiUang if this worked out for you, please accept as the correct answer!

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. I tried that earlier but that wasn't the problem. I got it to work though by removing the value you intialized for range on the first line and then removing .innerHTML from range just below the console.log. Then I added this line "document.getElementById('date_range').innerHTML = range;" and now it works perfectly. Thanks so much for the help. This really saved me.

Comment: The code above is working in the JSBin I posted - maybe it's some discrepancy with integrating it into your current markup?
While `document.getElementById()` is an inexpensive function, in general it's best practice to cache references to DOM elements as variables so Javascript only needs to look them up one time.

Comment: Ok. Thank you again.